# What is the "active Nix expression"?

Tags: nix, nixos

I notice that descriptions of various nixos commands refer to something called the "active Nix expression". For example, the man page for `nix-env` includes:

```
   --file / -f path
       Specifies the Nix expression (designated below as the active Nix expression) used by the --install, --upgrade, and --query
       --available operations to obtain derivations. The default is ~/.nix-defexpr.
```

What is this "active Nix expression"? Where is it defined? Is it simply what is written in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` ordinarily or instead what was defined by `nix-shell` otherwise?

Comment: `nix` and`nixos` (as tagged) are certainly "software tools commonly used by programmers", no? https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @KenWhite, Nix *is* a programming language (the language in which Nix derivations are written in, granted). I'm not so sure about this specific question insofar as it's focused on the command-line tools and not the programming language -- it's on shakier ground than most for that reason -- but *in general*, I'd call Nix questions topical here.

Comment: @mherzl, being a "software tool commonly used by programmers" is not good enough; something *also* needs to be "unique to software development"; see the **and** (not an "or"!) connecting bullet points 3 and 4 in the page you linked. If a system administrator or end user would use the same tool -- if it's not **unique** to software development -- then it's less squarely in Stack Overflow's purview.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I don't have an issue with the Nix topic in general. My query was about this specific question being programming related. I've removed the comment, however.

Comment: @KenWhite, ...as you can see above, I agree with you that this question isn't quite squarely inside the four corners of the topic, so it's definitely open to judgment/interpretation where to draw the line.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Agreed, which is why I asked the poster to explain in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the file from which the Nix expression in which any attribute specified with `-A` is evaluated. (Absent `-A`, that content is expected to directly be a derivation).

Let's say you have a `mydir/default.nix` file that evaluates to an attrset with keys `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`, each of which maps to a derivation as a value.

In this case, running `nix-env -f mydir -iA foo` will load `mydir/default.nix`, evaluate `foo` in the context of that loaded code, run any associated build steps, and add that software to your active environment.